# Outlook Web Access: "Outlook Web Access has encountered a Web browsing error"

Tags: outlook-web-access

When one of my colleagues is accessing Outlook Web Access from IE, he frequently gets an error reported: "Outlook Web Access has encountered a Web browsing error".

The error report includes the following:

> Client Information
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB5; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506)
>
> CPU Class: x86
>
> Platform: Win32
>
> System Language: en-gb
>
> User Language: en-gb
>
> CookieEnabled: true
>
> Mime Types:
>
> Exception Details
>
> Date: Tue Apr 6 16:46:54 UTC+0100 2010
>
> Message: Automation server can't create object
>
> Url: https://example.com/owa/x.y.z.a/scripts/premium/uglobal.js
>
> Line: 85

Any idea as to what might be causing such a problem?
The only solution suggested so far is "Reinstall Windows", which he'd rather avoid.

Comment: Do you know if it's a 2003-2007 exchange server. Do you have Java installed properly? If so, try a reinstall. Try this fix also posted on Expert-Exchange: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911829

Comment: Take a look at this also: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/2298bbea-51c9-4774-a820-4857f7b135b6

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem?